# Using the macro generated by \pgfmathprintnumberto in a \pgfmathparse or \SI

Tags: siunitx, pgfmath

To demonstrate, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{1 + 1}
    \pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfmathresult}{\calcResult}

    % Both this line
    \pgfmathparse{\calcResult + 1}

    % and this one
    \SI{\calcResult}{\cm}

    % do not work.
\end{document}
```

The errors I see are:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `$' or `$2' (in '$2$+ 1').

! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
!
! Invalid token '$' in numerical input.

! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
!
! Invalid numerical input '$2$'.
!
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
```

Comment: `\pgfmathprintnumberto{2}{\calcResult}` saves `$2$`. You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\calcResult}{1+1}`

Comment: @HarishKumar That makes sense, but I'd like to be able to use the rounded version provided by `\pgfmathprintnumberto` in the same way I can use the macro defined by `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: Use `int` → `\pgfmathsetmacro{\calcResult}{int(1+1)}`.

Comment: Answer added. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\pgfmathprintnumberto{2}{\calcResult}` results in `$2$`. You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\calcResult}{1+1}` directly. To round the number to integers you can use `int` as in `\pgfmathsetmacro{\calcResult}{int(1+1)}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\calcResult}{int(1+1)}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\calcResult}

    % Both this line
    \pgfmathparse{\calcResult + 1}
    \pgfmathresult

    % and this one
    \SI{\calcResult}{\cm}

    % do not work.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Harish's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235315) is spot on, but an alternative is to use the LaTeX3 FPU to do the work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SI{\fpeval{1 + 1}}{\cm}

\SI[round-integer-to-decimal, round-mode = places, round-precision = 1]%
  {\fpeval{1 + 1}}{\cm}

\end{document}
```